# How to execute a funcion callback as subprocess in python?

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, callback, subprocess

I'm currently learning how to use subprocesses, for this (and some other) reasons
I've bought a book to learn how to work with subprocesses. It's a good book
and I'm not having troubles understanding it. In my book they start to explain
how to execute shell commands as subprocesses.

I had a programming problem I had for ages, and with the subprocesses, I could
be able to solve it **but** I need to execute a function callback as subprocess.

I have this code to echo something but it's a shell command:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'Hello, this is child process speaking'],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = proc.communicate()
print(out.decode('utf-8'))
```

I want this callback to be executed as a subprocess:

```
def callb()
import time as t
print('2')
t.sleep(2)
    print('1')
t.sleep(2)
    print('0')
```

I just tried out to execute this callback like this (it was a simple naive idea):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(callb())
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/testfile.py", line 6, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen(callb())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 818, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1321, in _execute_child
    args = list(args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The strange thing is, that it **does** execute the callback, but then it raises this error!
What did I do wrong?  Did I forget something?

Comment: The function is called and returns None by default so you are basically calling `subprocess.Popen(None)`

Comment: So how can I avoid the Error?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do, there are probably easier ways to do what you want. What is the idea behind the callback logic?

Comment: I need to do some complicated and time taking calculations, I want them to be done all at the same time, thats quicker

Comment: Then you probably want the multiprocessing lib with a pool https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html, that also depends on the kind of work you are doing

Comment: What is this and how could I get it? Actually, I want to learn how to execute callbacks w. `subprocess`

Comment: I added a link to the docs, it is part of the standard lib

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108000/discussion-between-h-e-u-r-e-k-a-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `subprocess` module is not suitable for executing python callbacks.  you want to look at the [`multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) instead.  the first few examples with `Process` and `Pool` seem to do what you want.